# How to render resursively with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I got this long error:

```
Function opaque return type was inferred as '_ConditionalContent<_ConditionalContent<some View, VStack<ForEach<[Dictionary<String, JSON>.Keys.Element], Dictionary<String, JSON>.Keys.Element, TupleView<(some View, some View)>?>>>, some View>' (aka '_ConditionalContent<_ConditionalContent<some View, VStack<ForEach<Array<String>, String, Optional<TupleView<(some View, some View)>>>>>, some View>'), which defines the opaque type in terms of itself
```

I think the issue is the "resursive" character of the rendering as the error log itself says also:

> which defines the opaque type in terms of itself

If I replace in the second if-else-statement, as in comment you see, and return only a text, then I got no error.

```swift
@ViewBuilder
func showNode(json: JSON) -> some View {
    if let v = json.get() as? String {
        Text("\(v)").padding()
    } else if let d = json.get() as? [String: JSON] {
        VStack {
            ForEach(d.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { k in
                if let v = d[k] {
                    Text("\(k)").padding()
                    showNode(json: v)
                }
            }
        }
        // Text("").padding()
    } else {
        Text("").padding()
    }
}
```

Method is a recursive method, which should render a json tree.

And the `JSON`

```swift
public enum JSON {
    case string(String)
    case number(Float)
    case object([String:JSON])
    case array([JSON])
    case bool(Bool)
    
    func get() -> Any {
        switch self {
        case .string(let v):
            return v
        case .number(let v):
            return v
        case .object(let v):
            return v
        case .array(let v):
            return v
        case .bool(let v):
            return v
        }
    }
}
```

And all I do render it on screen:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var data: JSON? = nil

        init() {
        updateValue()
        return
    }
    
    mutating func updateValue() {
        do {
            if let jsonURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "user", withExtension: "json") {
                let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonURL)
                guard let d2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableLeaves) as? JSON else {
                    print("Can not convert to d2")
                    return
                }
                data = d2
            }
        } catch  {
            
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let data = self.data {
                showNode(json: data)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. What's `JSON` for instance?

Comment: ahh, yes, I added JSON

Comment: and some more data which loads the JSON from a file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`some View` is just a language feature that allows you to not write out the whole return type of the method.

If you actually try to write out the whole return type of the method by meticulously following all the language rules, you will find that you run into a problem. Because *you need to know what the return type of `showNode` is, in order to know the return type of `showNode`!* This is partly due to its recursive nature, and partly due to `@ViewBuilder`.

If you are wondering what on earth is `_ConditionalContent`, those come from [`buildEither`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildeither(second:)), which is what your if statements [translate into](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md#the-result-builder-transform) when put inside a `@ViewBuilder`. `TupleView` comes from [`buildBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildblock(_:_:)), and all their type parameters are determined by the types of the expressions you put inside, one of them being the `showNode` call, whose type we are in the middle of figuring out.

You can fix this by either using `AnyView`, the type-erased view:

```
func showNode(json: JSON, depth: Int = 1) -> AnyView {
    if let v = json.get() as? String {
        return AnyView(Text("\(v)").padding())
    } else if let d = json.get() as? [String: JSON] {
        return AnyView(VStack {
            ForEach(d.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { k in
                if let v = d[k] {
                    Text("\(k)").padding()
                    showNode(json: v)
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        return AnyView(Text("").padding())
    }
}
```

Or make a new `View` type to stop the infinite recursion:

```
struct NodeView: View {
    let json: JSON
    
    var body: some View {
        if let v = json.get() as? String {
            Text("\(v)").padding()
        } else if let d = json.get() as? [String: JSON] {
            VStack {
                ForEach(d.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { k in
                    if let v = d[k] {
                        Text("\(k)").padding()
                        NodeView(json: v)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Text("").padding()
        }
    }
}
```

A few additional notes:

- The way that you are parsing the JSON right now is incorrect. `JSONSerialization` won't give you your own `JSON` type. You should probably use a custom `Codable` implementation instead, but exactly how to do that belongs to another question.
- The view that this code draws doesn't actually show the "levels" of the JSON. Not sure if that is intended or not
- `if let v = json.get() as? String {` doesn't handle `Bool`s or `Float`s or arrays. If you want to handle those, you need to write checks for them as well.